# Missing GridLayout in Vaadin 14

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin14

Vaadin 8 has a Layout that is using a CSS grid to layout parts of a component [Vaadin Grid Layout](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/layout/layout-gridlayout).
With the help of this layout, you could have a grid, with cells spanning both horizontally and vertically over multiple columns and rows.
Now in Vaadin 14 there is no GridLayout any longer.
Vaadin tells us that now that FormLayout supports multiple Columns, in a way it replaces GridLayout ([link](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/migration/5-components/#formlayout)). I think that's not true for different reasons.

- contextually a FormLayout is supposed to be used on a form. But what if we want to layout other components?
- with GridLayout you have control over exactly where in the grid you want to place an element. I am yet to find a way to do that in a FormLayout
- there is no way to make elements span multiple rows as discussed on [github](https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/928)

Feel free to edit this question to add more points to this list.

Are there any good alternatives? (besides downgrading to vaadin 8, which is not a real alternative.)
One obvious solution would be to use a Polymertemplate or a Littemplate, but a solution working only with Java would certainly be preferred.
Another solution might be to put Layouts in other Layouts to build a layout that looks like a grid layout. But this would probably be harder to maintain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Css Grid Layout](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/css-grid-layout) in the Vaadin component directory.

There is a demo [here](https://appreciated-collection.herokuapp.com/grid-layout/)

It supports row and column spanning e.g. this example from the demo using the FluentGridLayout.withItemWithSize() method:

```
public class FlexibleGridLayoutExample2 extends HorizontalLayout {
    public FlexibleGridLayoutExample2() {
        FlexibleGridLayout layout = new FlexibleGridLayout()
                .withColumns(Repeat.RepeatMode.AUTO_FILL, new MinMax(new Length("190px"), new Flex(1)))
                .withAutoRows(new Length("190px"))
                .withItems(
                        new ExampleCard(), new ExampleCard())
                .withItemWithSize(new ExampleCard(), 2, 2) // add item with a custom size (2 rows and 2 cols)
                .withItems(
                        new ExampleCard(), new ExampleCard(), new ExampleCard(), new ExampleCard(), new ExampleCard(),
                        new ExampleCard(), new ExampleCard(), new ExampleCard(), new ExampleCard(), new ExampleCard(),
                        new ExampleCard(), new ExampleCard(), new ExampleCard(), new ExampleCard(), new ExampleCard(), 
                        new ExampleCard(), new ExampleCard(), new ExampleCard()
                )
                .withPadding(true)
                .withSpacing(true)
                .withAutoFlow(GridLayoutComponent.AutoFlow.ROW_DENSE) // allow the item order to be changed to let elements fill empty spaces.
                .withOverflow(GridLayoutComponent.Overflow.AUTO);
        layout.setSizeFull();
        setSizeFull();
        add(layout);
    }
}
```

You can also specify cell start and end positions using the FluentGridLayout. withRowAndColumn() method:

```
public class CssGridLayoutExample1 extends VerticalLayout {
    public CssGridLayoutExample1() {
        Component alignTestComponent = new ExampleCard();
        FluentGridLayout layout = new FluentGridLayout()
               .withTemplateRows(new Flex(1), new Flex(1), new Flex(1))
               .withTemplateColumns(new Flex(1), new Flex(1), new Flex(1))
               .withColumnAlign(alignTestComponent, GridLayoutComponent.ColumnAlign.END)
               .withRowAlign(alignTestComponent, GridLayoutComponent.RowAlign.END)
               .withRowAndColumn(alignTestComponent, 1, 1, 1, 3)
               .withRowAndColumn(new ExampleCard(), 2, 1)
               .withRowAndColumn(new ExampleCard(), 2, 2)
               .withRowAndColumn(new ExampleCard(), 1, 3, 3, 3);
        layout.setSizeFull();
        setSizeFull();
        add(layout);
    }
}
```

Comment: weird though, that we need a 3rd party tool for this.

Comment: Typically Vaadin

Answer (score 0):

Too late to the party, but you could use my implementation of the GridLayout:

```
   public class DwGridLayout extends Composite<Div> {

    private interface MatrixConsumer {
        void execute(int colIndex, int rowIndex);
    }

    private final static String CSS_CLASS_CELL_POSITION_COL_INDEX_PREFIX = "cell-pos-col-";
    private final static String CSS_CLASS_CELL_POSITION_ROW_INDEX_PREFIX = "cell-pos-row-";
    private final static String CSS_CLASS_CELL_CONTENT_DEFAULT = "cell-content-default";
    private final static String CSS_BORDER_STYLE = "1px solid grey";


    private final int amountOfColumns;
    private final int amountOfRows;
    private boolean displayBorder;
    private Div[][] colRowCellMatrix;

    public DwGridLayout(int amountOfColumns, int amountOfRows) {
        this.amountOfColumns = amountOfColumns;
        this.amountOfRows = amountOfRows;
        this.colRowCellMatrix = new Div[amountOfColumns][amountOfRows];
        this.getContent().getStyle().set("display", "grid");
        this.getContent().getStyle().set("grid-template-columns", "min-content ".repeat(this.amountOfColumns));
        this.getContent().getStyle().set("overflow-x", "auto");
        this.getContent().getStyle().set("width", "100%");

        initCellMatrix();
        reloadGridComposite();
    }

    private void initCellMatrix() {
        iterateOverMatrixAndExecute((colIndex, rowIndex) -> colRowCellMatrix[colIndex][rowIndex] = createCell(colIndex, rowIndex, null));
    }

    private void reloadGridComposite() {
        this.getContent().removeAll();
        iterateOverMatrixAndExecute((colIndex, rowIndex) -> this.getContent().add(colRowCellMatrix[colIndex][rowIndex]));

        if (displayBorder) {
            displayBorder();
        }
    }

    private void displayBorder() {
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < amountOfRows; rowIndex++) {
            colRowCellMatrix[0][rowIndex].getStyle().set("border-left", CSS_BORDER_STYLE);
            boolean atLeastOneWrapperHasContent = getComponentWrappersOfRow(rowIndex).stream()
                    .anyMatch(compWrapper -> !compWrapper.getClassNames().contains(CSS_CLASS_CELL_CONTENT_DEFAULT));
            if (atLeastOneWrapperHasContent) {
                for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < amountOfColumns; columnIndex++) {
                    colRowCellMatrix[columnIndex][rowIndex].getStyle().set("border-bottom", CSS_BORDER_STYLE);
                }
            }
        }
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < amountOfColumns; columnIndex++) {
            colRowCellMatrix[columnIndex][0].getStyle().set("border-top", CSS_BORDER_STYLE);
            boolean atLeastOneWrapperHasContent = getComponentWrappersOfColumn(columnIndex).stream()
                    .anyMatch(compWrapper -> !compWrapper.getClassNames().contains(CSS_CLASS_CELL_CONTENT_DEFAULT));
            if (atLeastOneWrapperHasContent) {
                for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < amountOfRows; rowIndex++) {
                    colRowCellMatrix[columnIndex][rowIndex].getStyle().set("border-right", CSS_BORDER_STYLE);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private List<Div> getComponentWrappersOfRow(int rowIndex) {
        List<Div> components = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfColumns; i++) {
            components.add(colRowCellMatrix[i][rowIndex]);
        }
        return components;
    }

    private List<Div> getComponentWrappersOfColumn(int columnIndex) {
        List<Div> components = new ArrayList<>();
        //noinspection ManualArrayToCollectionCopy
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfRows; i++) {
            components.add(colRowCellMatrix[columnIndex][i]);
        }
        return components;
    }

    private void iterateOverMatrixAndExecute(MatrixConsumer matrixConsumer) {
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < amountOfRows; rowIndex++) {
            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < amountOfColumns; colIndex++) {
                matrixConsumer.execute(colIndex, rowIndex);
            }
        }
    }

    private Div createCell(int columnIndex, int rowIndex, Component componentToInput) {
        Div div = new Div();
        div.getClassNames().add(CSS_CLASS_CELL_POSITION_ROW_INDEX_PREFIX + rowIndex);
        div.getClassNames().add(CSS_CLASS_CELL_POSITION_COL_INDEX_PREFIX + columnIndex);
        if (componentToInput == null) {
            div.getClassNames().add(CSS_CLASS_CELL_CONTENT_DEFAULT);
        } else {
            div.getClassNames().remove(CSS_CLASS_CELL_CONTENT_DEFAULT);
        }
        div.add(componentToInput == null ? new Div() : componentToInput);
        return div;
    }

    private void validateCoordinates(int columnIndex, int rowIndex) {
        if (columnIndex >= amountOfColumns) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ColumnIndex " + columnIndex + " is out of bounds of the grid. The biggest ColumnIndex in grid is: " + amountOfColumns);
        }
        if (rowIndex >= amountOfRows) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("RowIndex " + rowIndex + " is out of bounds of the grid. The biggest RowIndex in grid is: " + amountOfRows);
        }
    }

    public Component getComponent(int columnIndex, int rowIndex) {
        validateCoordinates(columnIndex, rowIndex);
        Div componentWrapper = colRowCellMatrix[columnIndex][rowIndex];
        return componentWrapper.getChildren().findFirst().orElseThrow();
    }

    public void addComponent(int columnIndex, int rowIndex, Component newComponent) {
        validateCoordinates(columnIndex, rowIndex);

        Div[][] matrixWithNewComponent = new Div[amountOfColumns][amountOfRows];
        iterateOverMatrixAndExecute((colIndexE, rowIndexE) -> matrixWithNewComponent[colIndexE][rowIndexE] =
                (colIndexE == columnIndex && rowIndexE == rowIndex)
                        ? createCell(colIndexE, rowIndexE, newComponent)
                        : colRowCellMatrix[colIndexE][rowIndexE]);
        colRowCellMatrix = matrixWithNewComponent;
        reloadGridComposite();
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.getContent().setId(id);
    }

    public void setDisplayBorder(boolean displayBorder) {
        this.displayBorder = displayBorder;
    }

    /**
     * <b style="color: red;">Beware: Adding a new Component to a position with a tooltip will remove the tooltip.</b>
     */
    public void addTooltipForComponent(int columnIndex, int rowIndex, String tooltip) {
        colRowCellMatrix[columnIndex][rowIndex].setTitle(tooltip);
        reloadGridComposite();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Label createDebugCell(int colIndex, int rowIndex) {
        return new Label(colIndex + ":" + rowIndex);
    }

}
```

You can use it like this:

```
DwGridLayout grid = new DwGridLayout(5, 9);
grid.setId("MyDwGridLayoutId");
grid.setDisplayBorder(true);
grid.addComponent(0, 0, createButtonWithSizeInPx(75, 75));
grid.addComponent(2, 6, createButtonWithSizeInPx(500, 100));
grid.addTooltipForComponent(2, 6, "Should not be displayed in 2,6");
grid.addComponent(2, 6, createButtonWithSizeInPx(500, 100));
grid.addComponent(2, 6, createButtonWithSizeInPx(500, 100));
grid.addComponent(4, 7, createButtonWithSizeInPx(300, 300));
grid.addComponent(3, 2, createButtonWithSizeInPx(100, 200));
grid.addTooltipForComponent(4, 7, "CRAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZYYYYYY 4,7");
```